# windows system tray application like the volume application

Tags: c#, system-tray, windows

I would like to create a application very similar to the windows 7 volume bar which is located in the system tray. I'm new to windows development and would like a point in the right direction.

- Should i just make a normal application and just put in the system tray?
- I don't need a main window for the application, it has to accessible   only via system-tray (i need only the volume bar, nothing else)... how can i do this?
- Would it be better to write it in C++ instead of C#?
- How can i detect the "volume" of the sound that is outputted by windows (even if the system sound is muted)?

Thanks for your reply's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can by using the class [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx). Just google for it to find samples. [Here is one](http://alanbondo.wordpress.com/2008/06/22/creating-a-system-tray-app-with-c/).

Comment: How do i display a small window with a volume bar when a user left clicks on the icon? Do i use a normal form and set the x/y coordinates?  thanks.

Comment: You should be able to show a form, choose a proper style to make it without caption and not shown in the taskbar

Comment: so the windows volume bar in the system tray is just a basic form which is position on top of the icon?

Comment: well, the windows volume bar is a system app probably written in C, and they have some low level facilities, but with c# we should eventually get to the same point.